# How to display birth year in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is display the details of customer whose birth year is 1980 want to display like this

```
Name | Surname | mob_no     |  city  | birth_year 
-------------------------------------------------
Jack | Jones   | 9892xxxxxx | Mumbai | 1980
```

**EDIT:**

data:

```
CUST_NO  FNAME    BIRTH_DATE    CITY           MOB_NO   DEPT_NAME    SALARY
------- -------- ------------- ----------  ----------   ------------ -------
   4583  Maitri   15-Aug-1997   Singapore  982xxxxxxx    Doctor       300000
   9087  Sajal    17-mar-1992   Nasik       991xxxxxx    Banker       180000
   6789  Yash     23-Feb-1980   Mumbai      123xxxxxx    Analyst      150000
   2346  Kriti    23-Feb-1980   Mumbai     99xxxxxxxx    Programmer    20000
```

In birth_date column there is birth year I want to display birth year and the details of employees.

This is what I have tried

```
select *
from table name 
where(birth_date) in (select birth_date 
                      from table name 
                      group by birth_date having count(birth_date)>1
                      )
order by birth_date;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. As is, without knowing your table structure, it's really hard to give a good answer; also, please post what you tried so far to show people that you did some effort and that you're not asking people to do the work for you

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, this is what you need:

```
select CUST_NO,
       FNAME,
       extract(year from BIRTH_DATE) AS BIRTH_YEAR,
       CITY,
       MOB_NO,
       DEPT_NAME,
       SALARY
from CUSTOMER
WHERE ...
```

Another way could be

```
to_char(BIRTH_DATE,'YYYY') AS BIRTH_YEAR
```

The first one gives a numeric value, while the second one gives the year as a string.

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: @RohanSadnani - These are workable solutions. If you get an error you're doing something different.

Comment: @Aleksej Oracle 11.2 version

Comment: Then the error must be somewhere else in your code; this works.

Comment: Thank You I will try it @APC